# jPlayer resume song from state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

Getting issue while resuming jPlayer song from old saved state using cookie.

I tried most of things and i saved current time state of jPlayer using :

```
$("#jplayer_N").data('jPlayer').status.currentTime
```

Above code works fine and i can save it in cookie.

But problem is when i do refresh how i get old saved state ? so song could play where it stoped. I am using jPlayerList also to add multiple songs.

I tried with this after search on google but this is not working.

```
myPlayerList.play(2, 20.29)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this :

```
$("#jplayer_N").jPlayer('playHead', 30);
```